# Having issues with content height scaling to 100% (CSS)

Tags: html, css, height

I've had a tough time trying to figure out what the issue with my CSS/HTML is, a new set of eyes taking a look would be greatly appreciated! I'm trying to get the content area to scale to the entire height of the page but it doesn't seem to be working in the example I've posted below. I've set both `body` and `html` to `height: 100%;` to no avail. Any ideas?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zVuyp/

(note that the CSS is an external resource linked to the left)

The page is not meant to scale to size so within the jsFiddle window it looks a bit odd, but the issue should still be clear enough. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height:auto` to body and it should work.